# Android - de-facto implementation of REST/JSON client?

Tags: java, android, json, rest

I'm new to Android development and wondering if there's a de-facto solution for REST/JSON client implementation. It looks like most of Android developers write their own implementations based on Apache HTTP client + GSON or org.json. I don't like the idea of writing all this code manually - is there anything I can use not to reinvent the bicycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 4 hours of looking for the answers, I decided to use CRest - http://crest.codegist.org/index.html. Seems to be what I was looking for.

**Update**

After 1.5 years, I still think it's really good solution.

Answer (score 1):

For Android's HTTP Clients, you can check out this blog post http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Android has integrated org.json, but you can use other JSON parser, such as GSON or Jackson.