# JSon Object Reading in java

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - de-facto implementation of REST/JSON client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464672/android-de-facto-implementation-of-rest-json-client)

How to read JSon object value in java.
I am sending  Http post request by using one URl. After that am getting result as a JSON object. I need to read that value. can any one give ideas.

Comment: Check this: [JSON Parsing example](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=JSON+Parsing+example)

Comment: otherwise post the response code here.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a library to deserialise the JSON for you, here are a couple I've used:

- [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
- [JSON.org](http://json.org/java/)

Comment: [StringTree](http://www.stringtree.org/stringtree-json.html) is very good too